# Azure SQL - Select Into - Update if exists, else create

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, insert-update

I am using Azure SQL for an Application DB, and am trying to create (and subsequently kep updated) some lightweight tables from the more complete tables the Application uses.

Main reason for this is that these tables will then be sync'd into a reporting DB using Azure Data Sync, which lets you be selective about the tables and columns you sync, but not the rows, so without having the smaller tables to use for sync, 99% of the data sync'd was superfluous to requirements.

I have been able to create the tables initially using SELECT INTO (cut down example of one below):

```
 select * INTO min_users
   from users where 
    id_object in (select id_user_create from min_all_tasks)
```

But as there is decades worth of data to deal with, this takes a LONG time, so just dropping the table and recreating it every time is not desirable.

I'm looking for a method to be able to incrementally update the tables once built by recording when this was last executed and selecting only rows have have been created or updated since the <date_last_executed>. e.g.

```
 select * INTO min_users
   from users where 
    date_arrive > <date_last_executed> AND
    id_object in (select id_user_create from min_all_tasks)
```

The key goal here is for the subsequent updates to be faster and insert rows if they don't already exists (according to the Primary Key) or updating them if they do, and (obviously) to not have duplicate rows as a result.

is there a relatively straightforward method to achieve this?

Everything I have been able to find just gives me tutorials on using SELECT INTO, or tells me how to perform an UPDATE to specific rows, but not an efficient way of Replacing a row that already exists.

It seems the [REPLACE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx) function in MySQL would do what I want, but I can't find any equivalent that will work in Azure SQL (REPLACE in SQL seems like it is more aimed at Find and Replace functions.

Comment: What is usually done is inserting non-existing rows (this is usually used in combination with WHERE NOT EXISTS filter), and updating existing ones (this is just a straight join between the rows). You can first copy all changed rows into a scratch table and then merge your copy and the scratch table by running insert and update

Answer (score 0):

**To achieve your key goal as insert rows if they don't already exist (according to the Primary Key) or updating them if they do, and (obviously) to not have duplicate rows as a result. In SQL, you may utilize the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command.** In order to efficiently synchronize data between tables, you may use the `MERGE` command, which combines insert and update actions into a single statement.

But for that you need to first create table with similar schema.

**Example Query:**

```sql
--create new table with same schema
SELECT  * INTO New_table FROM Old_table WHERE  1  =  0;

-- merge the tables.
MERGE INTO min_users AS target
USING (SELECT * FROM users WHERE date_arrive > [date_last_executed]
        AND id_object IN (SELECT id_user_create FROM min_all_tasks)
) AS source
ON target.primary_key = source.primary_key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        target.column1 = source.column1,
        target.column2 = source.column2,
        -- update other columns as needed
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (column1, column2, ...)
    VALUES (source.column1, source.column2, ...)
```

**My execution:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]